# I want to replace a string with it's grammatical opposite and print in an "Edit text" in android studio?

Tags: android, string, android-studio, replaceall

I have written this code to replace "is" with "was". I am not able to do so for more than one word. Can anyone please help me do so?

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText1, editText2 ;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String input = editText1.getText().toString();
                String replace =  input.replaceAll("is", "was");
                editText2.setText(replace);
            }
        });
`    }
```

Comment: can you post an example you tried ?

Comment: Can you explain more what do you want ?

Comment: @QuangTV i want to replace a verb with it's grammatical opposite. For Example : If i input this sentence " This is me", i want the output to be "That was me"

Comment: "I am not able to do so for more than one word." what does this mean exactly? Your code to replace the instances of "is" with "was" does work, you can see here: https://ideone.com/nn8QzG

Comment: @VividVervet I gave an example sentence, Input: "It is sunny" and i got the output :"It was sunny"

Comment: @R.ven This code already do it bro!

Comment: @R.ven then what is wrong in your code ? what you expect for the sentence "It is sunny" as output

Comment: @QuangTV, , I used the replaceAll() function and got what i wanted for one word. I am not able to do the same for the others. That is where i need your help.

Comment: @VividVervet Yes! it is okay for one word. I want it to work for all the other words also. not able to figure out what to do

Comment: @R.ven Lol, I dont really know what do you want ? You want replace more than 1 word or what. Please update question with input and output you want ?

Comment: @R.ven check the link posted by Andrew Brooke, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually create a mapping for this functionality. **Like create two arrays, one for present verb and one for past verbs. When you encounter any verb from present array, get its position by looping and matching through present array and then replace that from the verb of past array**. Keep the indexes of grammatically opposite verbs same in both arrays . That way you will be able to do that.
For eg .

**present array =[is,this]**

**past array=[was,that]**

Now if your sentence contains 'is' get its index i.e. 0 and **replace it with 0th position string from past array**

Answer (score 1):

for the rough way but it work for me !
for the example, what u get from edittext1 is "this is me !"

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String input = editText1.getText().toString();
            String replace =  input.replaceAll("is", "was");
            //now you get "this was me!"
            String replace2 = replace.replaceAll("this", "that");
            //now you get "that was me!"
            String replace3 = replace2.replaceAll("me", "yours");
            //at last your replace3 are now is "that was yours!"
            editText2.setText(replace3);
            //editText2 will now display "that was yours!"
        }
    });
```

I know this a rough way to do so, but it work well for me to replace more than one word:) good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot:), this definitely works for me. But I want to replace words other than this. This code will work perfectly for replacing "is", "this","me". But if i enter a sentence that contains none of these words? I want an idea for that.TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in single statement you can use this method

```
String strOutput = inString.replaceAll("call me","cm").replaceAll("as soon as possible","asap");
```

If you have many replacements, you better go with this approach

```
//array to hold replacements
String[][] replacements = {{"is", "was"}, 
                           {"this", "that"}};

//loop over the array and replace
String strOutput = inString;
for(String[] replacement: replacements) {
    strOutput = strOutput.replace(replacement[0], replacement[1]);
}

System.out.println(strOutput);
```

you can choose any of the method based on your requirement.